# Minify JSON with regex

Tags: regex, webstorm

## Problem Description

I want to minify a JSON. Meaning:

### Desired Result

**Before**

```json
{
  "keyOne": "First Value",
  "keyTwo": "Second Value"
}
```

**After**

```json
{"keyOne": "First Value", "keyTwo": "Second Value"}
```

I want to achieve this using RegEx.

What I tried is to replace `\s` with an empty string. But this leads to the unwanted result that whitespaces also gets removed from values:

### Result of Solution attempt

**Before**

```json
{
  "keyOne": "First Value",
  "keyTwo": "Second Value"
}
```

**After**

```json
{"keyOne": "FirstValue", "keyTwo": "SecondValue"}
```

## Research done / Solution attempts

- Searching Google and Stack Overflow, without success since all found questions target other use cases
- Honestly just fooling around with basic RegEx knowledge

---

To clarify the question: I do not want to do this in JavaScript. I know I can go to the console and run something like `copy(JSON.stringify(<the-json>))`.

I want to quickly do this in an editor, in this case [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/webstorm/) using the *Replace* Tool – without installing any plugins or switching tools.

[image]

---

## Final solution

To steps are needed:

1. Replace `\n` with an empty string. This removes linebreaks
2. Replace `\s+"` with `"` to remove whitespances.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Should there be a space after the colon in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two steps to achieve that in webstrom:

first replace `\n` with  (nothing!) to remove line breaks;

then `\s{2}"` with `"` to remove two whitespaces before each key;

Comment: Thanks! For the second step I used `\s+"` as search string, which removes any number of whitespaces. I will accept this as answer and post the final solution in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The way object is shown in JS isn't related to the way you can handle it;

```
{\n
  "keyOne": "First Value",\n
  "keyTwo": "Second Value"\n
}
```

the `\n` characters here are shown to make it more human readable, they don't actually exist in the object itself;

```js
const data = {
  "keyOne": "First Value",
  "keyTwo": "Second Value"
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

thus you can't apply regex to a regular JavaScript object;

however (very unlikely) if you have a string representation of an object (from somewhere?)
you can apply regex to achieve the result you want like shown in the snippet below:

```js
const strObj = `{
"keyOne": "First Value",
"keyTwo": "Second Value"
}`;

//since it is string we can't access it like normal js objects
console.log(strObj["keyOne"]);
console.log(typeof strObj, strObj);

//replacing the new line with nothing to make it linear
let result = strObj.replace(/\n/g,"")
console.log(typeof result, result);

//casting result to a valid json to an actual js object
let castedResult = JSON.parse(result);
// it will be shown as human readable since its normal object :)
console.log(typeof castedResult,castedResult);

//accessing one its attributes since its normal object now
console.log(castedResult.keyOne);
```

Comment: What if the strings contain new lines?

Comment: I should have written that I do not want to achieve this in JavaScript but in my IDE.
I updated the question.

Comment: @geoM I'd added another answer according to that